# Type parameter 'com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.stripe.android.model.StripeModel'

Tags: stripe-payments, alipay

Type parameter 'com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.stripe.android.model.StripeModel'

````
 private static final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment succeeded
            } else {
                // Payment failed/cancelled
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Payment failed
        }
    }
    ```
I used the official stripe example, but it kept reminding me of this problem:"Type parameter 'com.stripe.android.PaymentIntentResult' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.stripe.android.model.StripeModel'"

Hope to get the help of all the big guys, it is greatly appreciated.
````